# Bluetooth not detected Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, bluetooth

I have a Asus laptop R556L and I installed Xubuntu 16.04 and the bluetooth is not detected.

Running bluetooth manager shows:

```
Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue.
This probably means that there were no Bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetooth daemon was not started.
```

Running "ps -ef | grep blue" shows:

```
lawand    3527  3501  0 23:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet
lawand    3845  3185  0 23:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/bluetooth/obexd
lawand    5907  3625  0 23:57 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-manager
lawand    5917  3185  0 23:57 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-adapters
lawand    5949  5929  0 23:58 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto blue
```

Running "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb" shows:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AW-NE186H [1a3b:1186]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b483 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 062a:4101 Creative Labs Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I tried purging "blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth" and install them again but that didn't work.

I checked "sudo rfkill list":

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What errors do you get from sudo service bluetooth restart  ?

Comment: nothing, I tried running that and there was no console output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the laptop doesn't actually have a bluetooth device.

Comment: at least you showed what errors are thrown in case there's no bluetooth adapter :)